# How is ApplicationController automatically generated?

Tags: ember.js

The Ember.js apps

```
App = Ember.Application.create();
```

and

```
App = Ember.Application.create();
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend();
```

do the same because Ember automagically generates the ApplicationController. Correct?

So why can I access `App.ApplicationController` in the JavaScript console for the second app but not for the first one? When it is automagically generated I should be able to access it in the console. What is wrong about my assumption?

Comment: how are you trying to access the ApplicationController in the console?

Comment: By typing `App.ApplicationController` into the JavaScript console of a Chrome web browser. It is `undefined` for the first version but `App.ApplicationController` for the seconds version. Shouldn't be it the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's created in both cases, try this in the Javascript console:

```
//use only for debug purposes
App.__container__.lookup('controller:application');
```

this should give you the ApplicationController instance in both cases

altough you define your controller like so:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend();
```

if you want to `hook` into the controller

hope it helps